# Issue with Netbeans 8.0 + SASS-COMPASS: some partials are not compiling

Tags: netbeans, compass-sass

Dealing with a Magento project, I discovered the latest web responsive Magento theme (rwd) and the SASS-COMPASS concept it involves.
In order to build my own custom theme from the rwd one, I tried to set up Netbeans 8 in this way:

Here is my project tree:

```
Project root (local path C:\myproject)
|
---skin
   |--- frontend
        |---my_rwd
            |---default
                |---css
                |   |---styles.css
                |---scss
                   |---core
                   |   |---_corepartial1.scss
                   |   |---_corepartial2.scss
                   |---framework
                   |   |---_fwpartial1.scss
                   |   |---_fwpartial2.scss
                   |---styles.scss
                   |---_core.scss
                   |---_framework.scss
```

In a usual way, the main styles.scss is importing partials:

```
@import "framework.scss"
@import "core.scss"
```

And _core.scss...

```
@import "core/corepartial1.scss"
@import "core/corpartial2.scss"
```

...and _framework.scss ares importing "subpartials":

```
@import "framework/fwpartial1.scss"
@import "framework/fwpartial2.scss"
```

At the project root, I put a COMPASS config file like this:

```
project_path = 'C:\my_project\skin\frontend\my_rwd\default'
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
relative_assets = true
output_style = :expanded
environment = :development
```

And I set up Netbeans CSS-preprocessing like this:

```
x Compile Sass files on save

Input: /skin/frontend/my_rwd/default/scss
Output: /skin/frontend/my_rwd/default/css

Compiler options: --compass --debug-info --style compressed

SASS path: C:\Ruby200\bin\sass.bat
```

Big issue is: Everything's running perfectly when editing main styles.scss, _framework.scss or any framework subpartials (i.e. css files are compiled on save). But when I edit _core.scss or any of its subpartials, no recompilation occurs on save !
That puzzles me very deeply. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions a little old, but thought I would post my finding in case it helps some one else.

I had a similar issue and found that Netbeans prefers relative paths.

I had:

```
---css
   |--- styles.css
   |--- scss
        |--- styles.scss
        |---components
            |---_header.scss
            |---_footer.sscs
        |---config
            |---components.scss
```

`css/scss/config/components.scss` contained:

```
@import "components/header";
@import "components/footer";
```

Editing any file in `css/scss/components/` just would not trigger Netbeans compile on save.
However editing `css/scss/config/components.scss` or `css/scss/styles.scss` would trigger the compile and the sass would compile successfully.

I found that while absolute paths without the first / work in sass, Netbeans does not like them.
Using relative paths works for sass and Netbeans

So changing `css/scss/config/components.scss` to

```
@import "../components/header";
@import "../components/footer";
```

Fixed it for me